# How do I parse out a text file with AWK and fprint in BASH?

Tags: linux, awk, printf

**I have a sample.txt file as follows:**

```
Name         City    ST Zip CTY
John Smith   BrooklynNY10050USA
Paul DavidsonQueens  NY10040USA
Michael SmithNY      NY10030USA
George HermanBronx   NY10020USA
```

Image of input (in case if upload doesn't show properly)
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv7nX.jpg)

**Desired output is into separate columns as shown below:**

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK4rf.jpg)

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{printf "%13-s %-8s %-2s %-5s %-3s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' sample.txt > new.txt
```

**And it's unsuccessful with this result:**

```
Name          City     ST Zip   CTY

John          Smith    BrooklynNY10050USA

Paul          DavidsonQueens NY10040USA

Michael       SmithNY  NY10030USA

George        HermanBronx NY10020USA
```

Would appreciate it if anyone could tweak this so the text file will be in delimited format as shown above.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

With gawk you can set the input field widths in the `BEGIN` block:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "13 8 2 5 3" } { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }' fw.txt
Name          City     ST  Zip  CTY
John Smith    Brooklyn NY 10050 USA
Paul Davidson Queens   NY 10040 USA
Michael Smith NY       NY 10030 USA
George Herman Bronx    NY 10020 USA
```

If your awk does not have `FIELDWIDTHS`, it's a bit tedious but you can use `substr`:

```
$ awk '{ print substr($0,1,13), substr($0,14,8), substr($0,22,2), substr($0,24,5), substr($0,29,3) }' fw.txt
Name          City     ST  Zip  CTY
John Smith    Brooklyn NY 10050 USA
Paul Davidson Queens   NY 10040 USA
Michael Smith NY       NY 10030 USA
George Herman Bronx    NY 10020 USA
```

Comment: Hi, I have FIELDWIDTHS and this works great and it's very simple to remember.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sed** to insert spaces to specific positions:

```
 cat data.txt | sed -e 's#\(.\{13\}\)\(.*\)#\1 \2#g' | sed -e 's#\(.\{22\}\)\(.*\)#\1 \2#g' |sed -e '1s#\(.\{29\}\)\(.*\)#\1 \2#g' | sed -e '2,$s#\(.\{25\}\)\(.*\)#\1 \2#g' | sed -e 's#\(.\{31\}\)\(.*\)#\1 \2#g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the field lengths into an array then loop over `$0` and gather the substrings in regular awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=split("13 8 2 5 3",ar)} 
           {
             j=1
             s=""
             sep="\t" 
             for(i=1;i<n;i++) 
                 {s=s substr($0, j, ar[i]) sep; j+=ar[i]} 
             s=s substr($0, j, ar[i])
             print s
           }'   file
```

That uses a tab to delimit the fields, but you can also use a space if preferred.

Comment: This is very nice as well and it also works great!  Appreciate the thought process on this.  I didn't realize there are so many ways to do this until now.